# Randomly displace GPS points by 1) drawing random angle from original point and 2) random distance up to 5 kilometers in R with sf package

Tags: r, random, gis, spatial, r-sf

I've got a set of gps points from survey data where I need to randomly displace gps points taken at community centers according to a specific, prescribed protocol in order to maintain anonymity. That protocol is

For every point,

1. Convert the coordinates from decimal degrees to meters using a fixed conversion factor from degrees to radians and
   a scalor to correct for differences in the number of meters in a degree of latitude across the earth.
2. Generate a random direction by generating angle between 0 and 360, and converting the angle from degrees to radians.
3. Generate a random distance in meters of  0-5,000 meters for Rural points with 1% of
   rural points being given 0-10,000 meter distance.
4. Generate the offset by applying trigonometry formulas (law of cosines) using the distance as the hypotenuse and the
   radians calculated in step 2.
   xOffset = math.sin(angle_radian) * distance
   yOffset = math.cos(angle_radian) * distance
5. Add the offset to the original coordinate (in meters) to return the displaced coordinates.

My data is in a projected coordinate system, in sf format. I'm having trouble finding anything on stack overflow that would do something like this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I don't really know where to begin, other than to put my data into an sf object.

Per @Chris's request below, here is some publicly available data that should work for the example, even though it's not my data.

```
structure(list(Country = c("Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi", 
"Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi", "Malawi"), 
    Admin1 = c("Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", 
    "Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", "Central"), Facility.n = c("80 Block Clinic", 
    "ABC Community Clinic", "Adventist Health Centre Area 14", 
    "Alinafe Community Hospital", "Area 18 Health Centre", "Area 25 Health Centre", 
    "Bembeke Health Centre", "Benga Health Centre", "Bilira Health Centre", 
    "Biriwiri Health Centre"), Facility.t = c("Clinic", "Clinic", 
    "Health Centre", "Community Hospital", "Health Centre", "Health Centre", 
    "Health Centre", "Health Centre", "Health Centre", "Health Centre"
    ), Ownership = c("MoH", "FBO", "FBO", "FBO", "MoH", "MoH", 
    "FBO", "MoH", "MoH", "MoH"), Lat = c(-12.9236, -13.9684, 
    -13.9532, -13.3879, -13.9411, -13.8924, -14.3583, -13.3685, 
    -14.8256, -14.7608), Long = c(33.4455, 33.7414, 33.7785, 
    34.2434, 33.7807, 33.7739, 34.4245, 34.274, 34.8525, 34.5575
    ), LL.source = c("GPS", "GPS", "GPS", "GPS", "GPS", "GPS", 
    "GPS", "GPS", "GPS", "GPS"), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(548325.802970651, 
    8571271.02167297), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(580077.278844605, 
    8455643.42555632), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(584090.10850165, 
    8457311.77187753), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(634633.006173475, 
    8519628.94135809), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(584332.151295466, 
    8458649.29678556), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(583615.066572708, 
    8464038.07679378), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(653605.505145466, 
    8412173.30799691), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(637957.843551778, 
    8521757.99554544), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(699348.474713264, 
    8360138.4496112), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(667645.656281371, 
    8367549.65666082), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 548325.802970651, 
    ymin = 8360138.4496112, xmax = 699348.474713264, ymax = 8571271.02167297
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84 / UTM zone 36S", 
        wkt = "PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 36S\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 36S\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",33,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",10000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",32736]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Country = NA_integer_, 
Admin1 = NA_integer_, Facility.n = NA_integer_, Facility.t = NA_integer_, 
Ownership = NA_integer_, Lat = NA_integer_, Long = NA_integer_, 
LL.source = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yup, `dput(head(sf_object, n =10))`, as data at bottom of you post to facilitate play and assistance. For anonymous, perhaps protocol should suggest random distance of 1:5, as 0 distance wouldn't necessarily be anonymous.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the attention! I can't actually publish the data of the sf object because it's part of a study. It also needs to be between 0 and 5, which follows a relatively well known protocol outlined by the Demographic and Health Surveys (quoting from their protocol made it easier to get ours passed, since it's a very well established anonymization technique). Theoretically a point could land at the same spot, though each point in a set would be displaced individually.

Comment: So, create concentric circles {i:l} around your hub gps at some acceptable step of distances, sample the circles, and assign your origin gps to the sampled circles by exchanging origin to that point on the circle. Seems easier than going through the angle thing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I agree - it would be easier, but, unfortunately - I do need to follow the protocol. It has been done in some form, but, just can't find any example code.

I'll add 10 random points from another public dataset, if that would be easier to work from.

Comment: It's in effect the same thing, as at 5km it will be a circle. So, make a 5km  circle, sample the circle to the # of points you have at 'center', and assign 'location' to the sample points. Don't set.seed for additional anonymity. Any other approach that is reverse engineer-able would impinge on the desired privacy and essentially this is how protocol is coded, it seems.

Comment: I'm wondering, though, if the prescribed method of displacement would actually tend to have a higher density at the center. in a way that concentric circles would not. Either way, I'm also slightly lost at how I'd bulk assign a random gps point along one of those circles.

Comment: One 5km circle polygon, then `st_sample(my_secret_circle, size=#of_survey_participants, type='random', exact=TRUE, by_polygon=FALSE)`, and those are the respondents' locations, oh and a 10km circle for assignment of 1%, or something like that. Sorry, haven't read the protocol.